# PHP String vs Variable - Rendering content

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

Disclaimer: I am pretty new to PHP programming so this question my seem stupid, so please forgive my amateur-ness.

I am customizing some Drupal code to change a behavior so that I can get the name of block from UI -> Store it in a variable (db) -> Use this information to load appropriate block into UI.

Below is my code:

```
$blockModuleName = strval(render($content['field_block_module_name']));
$blockDelta = strval(render($content['field_block_delta']));
echo "<div>";
echo $blockModuleName;
echo $blockDelta;
echo gettype($blockModuleName);
echo "</div>";

$block = module_invoke($blockModuleName, 'block_view', $blockDelta);
print render($block['content']);
```

The output is like this:
[image]

As the output shows, the $blockModuleName and $blockDelta contains the exact value as I intended. But, the content are not loaded into the tile properly.

However, if I use the following code instead everything works as expected:

```
$blockModuleName = strval(render($content['field_block_module_name']));
$blockDelta = strval(render($content['field_block_delta']));
echo "<div>";
echo $blockModuleName;
echo $blockDelta;
echo gettype($blockModuleName);
echo "</div>";

$block = module_invoke('md_slider', 'block_view', '1');
print render($block['content']);
```

Here is the output:
[image]

I know this has to be something simple, kindly help me to fix this.

Comment: tell me what is your var_dump(blockDelta) and var_dump($blockModuleName)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently $blockModuleName and $blockDelta had some html tags which I was not able to make out using echo, coz the string is displayed after HTML is processed.

I was able to get the desired output using this:

```
$blockName = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_block_module_name');
$blockNameFirstItem = reset($blockName);
$blockNameFirstItemValue = $blockNameFirstItem['value'];
$blockDelta = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_block_delta');
$blockDeltaFirstItem = reset($blockDelta);
$blockDeltaFirstItemValue = $blockDeltaFirstItem['value'];
$block = module_invoke($blockNameFirstItemValue, 'block_view', $blockDeltaFirstItemValue);
print render($block['content']);
```